Application refuses to open, citing System.BadImageFormatException as issue
For the last year and a half, and on two Windows 11 clean installations, I have been using Logitech's Onboard Memory Manager (OMM) to manage the binds on my mouse (the G502X Lightspeed). Last weekend, I did another clean install of Windows 11, this time version 24H2 (26100.2314). Now all of a sudden, the application does not want to launch. I have the same drivers I've been using since I got the mouse, so i crossed that out. Older versions of the application were also mot opening, so its not the application.
Hours of googling phrases like "onboard memory manager not opening" produced nothing.
A while later I opened Reliability Monitor to look at errors unrelated to the OMM problem and I instantly noticed the wall of critical events related to Onboard Memory Manager.
Here is one of the entries:
Source
OnboardMemoryManager

Summary
Stopped working

Date
‎12/‎7/‎2024 8:00 PM

Status
Report sent

Description
Faulting Application Path:  C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\OnboardMemoryManager\OnboardMemoryManager_2.2.5062.exe

Problem signature
Problem Event Name: CLR20r3
Problem Signature 01:   OnboardMemoryManager_2.2.5062
Problem Signature 02:   2.2.5062.0
Problem Signature 03:   66ea736d
Problem Signature 04:   mscorlib
Problem Signature 05:   4.8.9290.0
Problem Signature 06:   67214b29
Problem Signature 07:   43f6
Problem Signature 08:   a4
Problem Signature 09:   System.BadImageFormatException
OS Version: 10.0.26100.2.0.0.768.101
Locale ID:  1033
Additional Information 1:   fe71
Additional Information 2:   fe719b23ae8b2d7c6e941df86d80f491
Additional Information 3:   c708
Additional Information 4:   c70862cbc9e49aa050e715d1b3ed7c81

Extra information about the problem
Bucket ID:  7805f3e8acd2d6334213aab023ba186b (1302572390730569835)


Another hour or so of googling and the closest thing I found related tomy situation was this this post. Along with this, there were some results that point to a problem with my .NET version, but I confirmed with powersehll that i have it installed.
PSChildName Version
----------- -------
Client      4.8.09032
Full        4.8.09032
Client      4.0.0.0[enter link description here][2]

I'm at my wits end, so any help is appreciated.
Here is a specsheet of my laptop if that helps in any way.
Update:
Ok, so the problem may not be Windows, or maybe it is. I don't know anymore. I had a Windows 10 USB laying around (My laptop came with W10) so I decided to install it and... Onboard Memory Manager still doesn't launch. A whole OS downgrade. It has to be a missing software component because the the issue is obviously not tied to the OS. I already explored the .NET route but installing Desktop Runtime versions 6, 8, 9.

Sadly, you have not provided enough information to diagnose why the application is not running. You are likely correct that your .NET Framework installation is corrupt, sadly if that is the case, there is no way to reinstall (or uninstall and then reinstall) .NET Framework 4.8.1 on Windows 11. The only recourse in that case is a complete reinstall of Windows.

@Ramhound is there anything else I can provide? I'd be a pain to have to do another reinstall.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@CollChuuk - I would be sure to download a fresh ISO if you do.

@Ramhound Would an ISO be better that just using the Media Creation Tool. Thats what I've been using.

@Ramhound I went ahead and did a full reinstall and the problem still persists. I'm just going now do one of 23H2 and see why happens. Cuz at this point I'm convinced that it's the windows version.

I suspect the application requires .NET Framework 9, you can rule out a corrupted windows image, by running any .NET Framework 4.8 application you can find.

@Ramhound I installed Desktop Runtime 9 through 6, All of which came with Runtime and the program still wouldn't open

So CLR20r3 is definitely a .NET Runtime error, and .NET Framework 4.8.1 isn’t being updated anymore other than security updates, so something is causing your .NET to become corrupt.

@Ramhound see update

Try OMM 2.1.7479

@Ramhound See my answer. I'll be jumping off a bridge now.

Update: "Wait, so it was a C++ Redistributable problem? Always has been."
So basically, I installed G-HUB. OMM Worked after that. Then I got curious, what did the installation of G-HUB do that allowed OMM to work. I looked through some logs and found that a couple of Visual C++ Runtimes we're installed along with G-HUB.

So I went and uninstalled both G-Hub and the Visual C++ Runtimes and attempted to launch OMM again. It did not launch. I then downloaded and installed the latest redistributable offered by Microsoft. After which, OMM launched. I don't understand why Logitech omitted this requirement.
